# Two sprites collide - which one rear ended the other?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, collision

I am writing a simple game (in Javascript) where circular sprites can collide with each other. I store an angle (in degrees) and an x,y for each object. I have the collision detection working, but I need to work out which sprite hit the other. So for two objects colliding which one drove into the other (i.e. the front of which sprite made contact with the 'non front' of the other). Or to put it another way, which one rear ended the other. In the case of very close head on accidents e.g. where they make an absolute direct head on collision (180 degree collision) or are within say 5 degrees of doing so (175-185 degree collision), then I need to spot this and attribute no 'blame' to either sprite. What would the maths, or better still the code, for this be?

```
     var angleA = Math.abs(collidedWith.angle - 180);
     var angleB = Math.abs(this.angle - 180);
     var angleConsideredHeadOn = 5;
     var anglesSubtracted = Math.abs(angleA - angleB);

     if (anglesSubtracted < angleConsideredHeadOn) {
         var headOn = true;
     }


     if (anglesSubtracted >= angleConsideredHeadOn) {
         // There was a non-head on crash

         var xA = collidedWith.velocityX;
         var yA = collidedWith.velocityY;
         var xB = this.velocityX;
         var yB = this.velocityY;
         // Need to determine which sprites 'front' collided with the other's side or read
     }
```

Comment: Hi Hugh, unfortunately you're unlikely to really get a response for this without showing us code or algorithms you have tried.  Stack overflow is a "we will help you solve problems you have already attempted", not a "tell us you're problem and we'll do it for you".   Post up some code and have a crack at implementing your own algorithm, and then you'll probably see some answers.  Cheers :)

Comment: Don't you have some variable (or variables) storing momentum? Wouldn't that be the place to look.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Matt Burland - good thinking! At one point I resolve the angle into an X and Y direction/speed - I'm going to try and compare those for both sprites! Many thanks. I'll report back and post the code if I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the head-on case, take the dot product of their two (pre-impact) velocity vectors which will give you the cosine between their headings.  If that value is less than -0.9 Pi then the collision is head on.

Otherwise, the sprite to blame is the one with the highest absolute velocity (since a slow sprite cannot possibly rear-end a fast sprite).

Comment: The slower sprite could perform a side on hit. The key thing is that the front of one sprite has hit the side or rear of the other sprite. The could also have the same velocity. The velocity I store is in the form of an X and Y velocity where a negative number means its travelling up (for Y) or left (for X).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
// Javascript
// Two objects 'this' and 'collidedWith' have collided
// this code determines who head butted the other
// Based on having an angle and an X and Y velocity (xDir and yDir) where volicity could be negative (going left or up) or positive (going right or down)
// 'degrees' is a function which converts radians to degrees

var angleConsideredHeadOn = 15;

var theta_a = degrees(Math.atan2(this.xDir, this.yDir));
var theta_b = degrees(Math.atan2(collidedWith.xDir, collidedWith.yDir));

var a_to_b = degrees(Math.atan2(this.posY - collidedWith.posY, this.posX - collidedWith.posX)); // Normal angle from 'this's perspective
var b_to_a = -a_to_b % 360; // ditto from collidedWith's perspective

var collision_angle_a = Math.abs(theta_a - a_to_b) % 360
var collision_angle_b = Math.abs(theta_b - b_to_a) % 360

// Collision is close to head on
if (Math.abs(collision_angle_a - collision_angle_b) < angleConsideredHeadOn) return;

// 
if (collision_angle_a < collision_angle_b) {

    // 'collidedWith' head butted the other object

} else {

    // 'this' head butted the other object

}
```